# How to set up Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to python (and in coding in general). I'd like to ask some help to set up python on VS Code. I've tried to follow several guides but none of them were really helpful.

The following have been downloaded:

- Python 3.6
- VS Code
- Python extensions

Comment: This is a very broad question and hard to answer. If you make some more progress on your own then perhaps you can instead post a question to specific problems that you encounter.

Answer (score 3):

1) Install VS Code

2) Go to View > Command Palette

3) Type ext install and click on Install Extensions

4) Search for Python and install it

5) Reload VS

6) Start coding

Comment: Thanks Zroq. Can you please explain these json files: launch, setting, tasks. Also, I've read many forums where they suggested to declare the path and setup these files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

### .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "python.exe"
}
```

### .vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

### .vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }    
    ]
}
```

You can replace `"program": "${file}",` with `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.py",` to run your main file no matter which file you've selected but I found that that makes errors like syntax errors sometimes not display correctly if at all.

### Breaking on exceptions

1. Press `CTRL + SHIFT + D`
2. In the `BREAKPOINTS` panel, click on `Uncaught Exceptions`
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smmjm.png)